# MySQL case insensitive query with strings with whitespace

Tags: php, mysql, string

So I am trying to do a fairly simple task, compare a string with a mysql table row/entry using eg.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE $string = table_column.
```

My issue is, is that it is searching and remaining case sensitive.

```
The string: "A Long String"
The database entry "A Long String"
```

My table is collated: `latin1_swedish_ci`   which should be searching in case insensitive (like the rest of my queries), I believe since the strings contain whitespace it could be the issue, it is only looking at the first character's capitalisation.

I have tried using 'Upper' and 'lower' comparisons in my queries as well as using 'LIKE' I have also tried removing whitespace using REPLACE but I am probably doing it wrong, not entirely sure. But it never seems to find the correct entry unless I type it as it is in the database.

Any advice would be cool!

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM character_information WHERE 
(reference LIKE '".$origin_name."' AND char_name LIKE '".$char_name."') 
OR
(lower(reference) LIKE '".$origin_name."' AND lower(char_name) LIKE '".$char_name."') 
OR
(upper(reference) LIKE '".$origin_name."' AND upper(char_name) LIKE '".$char_name."') 
AND 
(char_gender = '".$char_gender."')");
```

Another try?

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM character_information WHERE 
reference = '".$origin_name."' AND char_name = '".$char_name."' AND char_gender = '".$char_gender."'");
```

I know this one is completely wrong, not meant to use REPLACE in this kind of way im assuming, should be used in UPDATE or INSERT? Anyway you can see what I am trying to do by removing the whitespace from everything.

```
$origin_name = str_replace(' ', '', $origin_name);
$char_name = str_replace(' ', '', $char_name);

$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM character_information WHERE 
( (REPLACE(reference, ' ', '' )) LIKE '".$origin_name."' AND (REPLACE(char_name, ' ', '' )) LIKE '".$char_name."%') 
AND 
(char_gender = '".$char_gender."')");
```

Comment: Please give the exact code (for example: what is "$string"?). Are you sure that the strings are equal? In some languages characters exist that look similar when displayed but are not (when using Unicode).

Comment: I think query must be in this manner SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE table_column = $string .

Comment: I used that as an example, I know how to write a mysql query in PHP (i have quotes in it), I already tried using lower and upper. I will post my code.

Comment: Okay, yes please post your code.

Comment: If you statically pass it a value does it work? Something like `SELECT * FROM character_information WHERE char_gender = 'male'`

Comment: I tried doing that in a test file and I still got no match, it does work if I put everything exactly the same as the database entry, so I am not sure...

Comment: The gender is not the issue, its just the other two which are longer strings with whitespaces, since gender is from radio button input from a html form.

Comment: when you use LIKE you should use %$char_name% to do the search

Answer (score 1):

Upper and lower comparisons aren't needed at the same time. If you convert both the column in your database and the search term to one or the other as part of the same query, you'll be ensuring case insensitivity.

```
mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE LOWER(table_column) = LOWER(\'' . $value . '\')');
```

Or for checking if a column *contains* the value rather than being equal to it:

```
mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE LOWER(table_column) LIKE LOWER(\'%' . $value . '%\')');
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will use this if I need it in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

I just realised what I was doing wrong,

It WAS returning a result but after I got the result I was comparing both of them in an if statement, eg/ $string == $db_string (which I don't need to, I don't know why I did this) and it was giving me 'false' since PHP takes into account case sensitive data.

Sorry guys!